# AWS ACM Imported certificate Notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, aws-acm

How can i implement or Automate some steps which will send certificate renewal status to custom channel ( e.g Email or Pagerduty/NewRelic) with condition something like ( If certificate is going to expire in 30 days, send notification)

i have found, AWS ACM does not renew imported certificates, and it sends expiration notifications on PHD ( Personal health dashboard as event notifications)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/check-certificate-renewal-status.html

is there a way i can use above functionality/service to automate desired steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Lambda function to send alerts to Slack and other systems based on PHD(Personal health dashboard) notifications. There is also an option to send an email/SMS via AWS SNS based on these events.
You can find more details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/cloudwatch-events-health.html)